# WCF Site Blocked by McAfee, how to unblock without turning off firewall

Tags: wcf, iis, firewall

McAfee's firewall was blocking me from using a WCF client I made in C# .NET over a local network until I disabled it.  How can I keep the firewall up and add an exception or something for my stie hosted in IIS?  Like when the firewall is up, navigating to http://mark-pc from the other computers comes up with nothing but if you turn off the firewall it comes up with my locally hosted IIS site (which is what I want).  I dont want to turn off the whole firewall so how can I just let that connection go out?

Even when I allow Port 80 though McAfee, it doesn't work.  They can view it in a browser but trying to ping mark-pc fails.

Comment: Have you unblocked/added a firewall exception in McAfee for port 80 or is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: It seems that unblocking port 80 allows the other computers to access the page in a web browser but my WCF client still program doesn't work

Comment: It's possible that McAfee is targeting your wcf client directly and not allowing any communication to/from it.  Try adding an exception for the client application.

Comment: Giving IIS and my client full internet access doesn't do anything, when I ping "mark-pc" i get a request timed out unless I disable the firewall

Comment: Pinging is often blocked by firewalls, so that really won't help your diagnostics.  I personally don't use McAfee, so I'm afraid I can't help much further.

Comment: This should be migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: Can I keep it here so I can offer a bounty?  Its important.